# Trying to run a bind method in a scope-isolated directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does this not work ?

---

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <sun external-fct="changeValue(internalValue)"></sun>
</div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
controllers.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.changeValue = function (newValue) {
        $scope.value = newValue;
    }

    $scope.$watch('value', function (n, o) {
        if (n !== o)
            alert('the value has changed to ' + n);
    });

}]);
```

**directives.js**

```
directives.directive('sun', function () { return {

    scope: {
        fct: '&externalFct'
    },

    template: '<button>click me</button>',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.on('click', function (e) {
            scope.fct({
                internalValue : 'test'
            })
        });
    }
}});
```

When I click on the `<button>`, the directive's external scope doesn't `$watch` the changed value!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>WWHOOPS !</kbd> I just forgot to run a `$digest()` on click !